# A countdown clock in TypeScript

Tags: timer, typescript

The gist of the code is, you give it a date, it will start counting down how many days, hours, minutes and seconds left by emitting an event 'countDown' and once 0 is reached 'expired' event is emitted.

How can this code be improved?

```
class DateCountDown {
    listeners: Map<string, Array<Function>>;

    constructor(date: Date) {

        this.startCountDown(date);
        this.listeners = new Map();
        this.listeners.set("countDown", []);
        this.listeners.set("expired", []);
    }

    on(eventName: "countDown", listener: (values: CountDownValues) => void);
    on(eventName: "expired", listener: (isExpired: boolean) => void);
    on(eventName: string, listener: Function) {
        this.listeners.get(eventName).push(listener);
    }


    startCountDown(date: Date) {
        const thousand = 1000;
        const sixty = 60;
        const twentyfour = 24;

        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            const now = new Date().getTime();
            const t = date.valueOf() - now;

            const days = Math.floor(t / (thousand * sixty * sixty * twentyfour));
            const hours = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty * sixty * twentyfour)) / (thousand * sixty * sixty));
            const minutes = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty * sixty)) / (thousand * sixty));
            const seconds = Math.floor((t % (thousand * sixty)) / thousand);

            if (t <= 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                this.listeners.get("expired").forEach(listener =>
                    listener(true));
                return;
            }

            this.listeners.get("countDown").forEach(listener =>
                listener(new CountDownValues(days, hours, minutes, seconds))
            );
        }, 1000);
    }
}
    class CountDownValues {
    days: number;
    hours: number;
    minutes: number;
    seconds: number;

    constructor(days: number, hours: number, minutes: number, seconds: number) {
        this.days = days;
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

}
var date = new Date();
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 20);

let countDown = new DateCountDown(date);

countDown.on("countDown", values => {
    console.log("from first", values);
});
countDown.on("expired", isExpired => {
    console.log("expired:", isExpired);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, taking a look at your code as a consumer of your API:

1. I like that the autocomplete for `.on("` shows what events I can listen to.
2. How do I stop listening to an event? If I don't want `countDown` events anymore then I have to do `countDown.listeners.get("countDown")!.splice(index, 1)` which is ugly.
3. How do I cancel a countdown?
4. Why is `listeners` exposed? This is an internal property of your class that I shouldn't need to know about as a consumer. It should be either `private` or `protected`. It's also probably worth marking `startCountDown` as `private` or `protected`.
5. Why does the `expired` event pass an extra parameter, `isExpired`? If the `expired` event is fired, doesn't that imply that the countdown is expired?
6. The `countDown` event is not fired every second. What happened to second 9 and 6?

   This is a common problem with timers, and is present in (almost) every JavaScript clock/timer question on this site. There are several possible solutions, the simplest of which is to check the time more frequently. The [MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) on it is worth reading.

   [![broken countdown ticks][1]][1]

#### TypeScript specific notes:

1. Turn on strict null checks. Yesterday. Without it, TypeScript ignores a whole class of errors.
2. Turn on no implicit any. Once turned on this will point out that the `on` method has a return type of `any`
3. Don't create a class to just hold properties. An interface is fine.

   ```ts
   interface CountDownValues {
       days: number;
       hours: number;
       minutes: number;
       seconds: number;
   }
   ```
4. Consider initializing properties where they are declared when using classes.

#### Other:

1. `new Date().getTime()` can be more concisely written as `Date.now()`
2. The `thousand`, `sixty`, and `twentyfour` variables make it harder to read your code. Get rid of them. You can make the code more readable by instead defining `day`, `hour`, etc.
3. Countdown is a word, you don't need to capitalize the D.
4. Using a map for events here is probably overkill. There are only two events and they are both known at compile time. I'd just use an object.
5. `countDown` is kind of an odd name for an event, without looking at your code I had no idea when it would be fired. I prefer `tick`, but there are other good options.

#### Rewrite:

I kept the feature set *mostly* the same, but wanted to add the ability to stop the timer, remove event listeners, and initialize a countdown before starting it. I let this run for ~15 minutes, and it never skipped a second or repeated one twice, which isn't conclusive, but I'm fairly confident it is stable.

Note that instead of firing the `tick` function multiple times per second, I do some math to figure out how long to wait and then schedule a tick based on that. This results in some more complicated code, but avoids the need to track what the last reported second was.

```ts
interface TickEvent {
    days: number;
    hours: number;
    minutes: number;
    seconds: number;
}

interface CountdownEvents {
    tick(values: TickEvent): void;
    expired(): void;
    stop(): void;
}

// Unfortunately we can't use T[K][] without getting messy.
type EventMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Function[] };

class Countdown {
    private listeners: EventMap<CountdownEvents> = { tick: [], expired: [], stop: [] };
    private timer?: number;

    on<K extends keyof CountdownEvents>(eventName: K, listener: CountdownEvents[K]): void {
        this.listeners[eventName].push(listener);
    }

    off<K extends keyof CountdownEvents>(eventName: K, listener: CountdownEvents[K]): void {
        const listeners = this.listeners[eventName];
        const index = listeners.indexOf(listener);
        if (index !== -1) {
            listeners.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    start(date: Date) {
        const end = Math.floor(date.getTime() / 1000);

        const tick = () => {
            const now = Date.now();
            const nowSec = Math.floor(now / 1000);
            const time = end - nowSec;

            if (time <= 0) {
                delete this.timer;
                this.listeners.expired.forEach(listener => listener());
                return;
            }

            const minute = 60;
            const hour = minute * 60;
            const day = hour * 24;

            const days = Math.floor(time / day);
            const hours = Math.floor(time % day / hour);
            const minutes = Math.floor(time % hour / minute);
            const seconds = time % minute;

            this.listeners.tick.forEach(listener => listener({ days, hours, minutes, seconds }));

            const timeToNextSecond = (nowSec + 1) * 1000 - now;
            this.timer = setTimeout(tick, timeToNextSecond);
        }

        tick();
    }

    stop() {
        if (this.timer) {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
            delete this.timer;
            this.listeners.stop.forEach(listener => listener());
        }
    }
}

const countdown = new Countdown();
countdown.on("tick", event => console.log("tick", event));
countdown.on("expired", () => console.log("expired"));
countdown.on("stop", () => console.log("stopped"));

const date = new Date();
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + 20);
countdown.start(date);

setTimeout(() => countdown.stop(), 3 * 1000);
```

Comment: Perfect, will use ur rewrite and follow all the notes going forward for ts development.  Thanks again for taking the time to write such a detailed reply/review